# Help me find out the number using venn diagram logic!

Tags: probability

I've been working on some numbers and recall that I can solve this with the Venn Diagram logic, unfortunately I've forgotten all my basic math on this.

Here is the data:
1. I have total 42885 (E) number of error. This error composes of 3 smaller entities: error a, error b, error c.
2. Error A = 40148, Error B=6220, Error C=3121.

Simply,
$$A+B+C>E$$

So, I would like to know how what is the real number of each error A, B and C??

Someone enlighten me please!

Comment: What do you mean by "real number of each error"? Didn't you just list "Error A = 40148, ..."?

Comment: If you want to know the sizes of the intersections $A\cap B$, etc. you don't have enough data for that. From what you wrote you can use the inclusion–exclusion principle to get the intersection of all, i.e. $|A\cap B\cap C|= |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cup B \cup C|$ supposing  $|E| = |A\cup B \cup C|$